# Why Golang string.Builder String() can convert []byte to slice without a reflect.StringHeader?

Tags: string, go

Go's strings package defines a Builder type which has a String() method

```
func (b *Builder) String() string {
    return *(*string)(unsafe.Pointer(&b.buf))
}
```

as reflect pacakge indicates, a byte slice is defined as a SliceHeader and an associated data block pointed by the header's Data field:

```
type SliceHeader struct {
  Data uintptr
  Len  int
  Cap  int
}
```

and string is defined as a StringHeader and an associated data block pointed by the header's Data field

```
type StringHeader struct {
  Data uintptr
  Len  int
}
```

the SliceHeader has 3 fields(Data, Len and Cap) and StringHeader has only 2(Data and Len),
so how can one convert byte slice to string directly like this ?

```
*(*string)(unsafe.Pointer(&buf))
```

in my understanding, we should code following:

```
func byte2str(b []byte) string {
  hdr := (*reflect.SliceHeader)(unsafe.Pointer(&b))
  return *(*string)(unsafe.Pointer(&reflect.StringHeader{Data: hdr.Data, Len: hdr.Len}))
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's break it down.

The expression `&buf` is a pointer to the slice header. A pointer to a slice is a pointer to the slice header.

The expression `(unsafe.Pointer(&buf)` is a [conversion](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Conversions) from the slice header pointer to an `unsafe.Pointer`. The unsafe.Pointer type has a magical property — it can be converted to and from any other pointer type.

The expression is `(*string)(unsafe.Pointer(&buf))` is a conversion from a slice header pointer to a string header pointer. A pointer to a string is a pointer to the header.

At this point, we have a string header pointer that's actually pointing to a slice header.  That might seem bad at first glance, but all is good. The memory layout of a string header is a prefix of the memory layout for a slice header.

The expression `*(*string)(unsafe.Pointer(&buf))` dereferences the string header pointer to get the string. This operation copies data and length fields from the slice header to a string header.

This code will break if the slice header fields are reordered without a corresponding change to the string header fields, but that's never going to happen.

Comment: Thanks for answering my question! I got it StringHeader is a subclass of SliceHeader

Comment: @SimonChen: "subclass" isn't a good way to describe it, because that term usually means very different things in programming languages (and Go has no definition of classes to begin with). Prefix is the most accurate, since we are only concerned with the memory layout of the two types and how they overlap.